# prevent express middleware from executing for same parent path

Tags: node.js, express

This is my code when.
I am hitting put API it is executing middleware 3 times but it should execute for put API only.

```
app.use('/api/user', MiddlewareFun);
  app.get('/api/user', (req, res) => {
     //do something
});

app.use('/api/user', MiddlewareFun);
app.post('/api/user', (req, res) => {
    //do something
});

app.use('/api/user', MiddlewareFun);
app.put('/api/user', (req, res) => {
    //do something
});
```

please don't say use like this.

```
app.put('/api/user', MiddlewareFun, (req, res) => {
   //do something
});
```

Comment: 3 Times app.use. why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's happening, because you've made it to. If you want the middleware, to be executed at only selected method, you have to specify it. For example:

Instead of doing:

```
app.use('/api/user', MiddlewareFun)
app.put('/api/user', (req, res) => {
     //do something
})
```

replace `use` method with `put`. As you'd bind regular route:

```
app.put('/api/user', MiddlewareFun)
app.put('/api/user', (req, res) => {
     //do something
})
```

Also, one more thing. You don't have to duplicate your middleware call before every route declaration. If you want to apply a middleware to your whole router, you can use `.use()` (as you did), or `.all()`; which will result in the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The middlewares in Express are binded to app or to router.
The solution to yuur problem is to check the method of the request object at the middleware

```
let MiddlewareFun = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    // do something
  }
  next()
}
app.use('/api/user', MiddlewareFun);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, You need to write express middleware which is part of your app or router. You can write as many middlewares you want, but in your case you just need it only once and here is the implementation of that.

```
const MiddlewareFun = function(req, res, next) {
  // req is object which consist of information about request made.
  // From req object you can get method name which is called.

  if(req.method.toLowerString() === 'put') {
     // your logic goes here
  }

  next();
}

app.use('/api/user', MiddlewareFun);

app.get('/api/user', (req, res) => {
  //do something
});

app.post('/api/user', (req, res) => {
   //do something
});


app.put('/api/user', (req, res) => {
  //do something
});
```